# Calling MVC controller methods to update specific partials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I have created a simple HttpHandler and socket management class in an ASP .Net MVC application to allow websocket communication with remote devices.

In the MVC app I have 2 Views each with their own controller; "DeviceList" and "DeviceDetail". When a new websocket connection is made, the HttpHandler passes the websocket to the socket management class.

How do I then "notify" the DeviceList controller that a new connection has been made so it can re-render the DeviceList view ?

Comment: Hello... I've not used it myself yet, but I believe the Javascript SignalR client can handle this notification pattern. We use it to force dashboard updates out to a number of sites.

Comment: Not really an option for us as the remote apps we want to communicate with are Ionic / Angular apps and we dont want to introduce jQuery (which is a dependency of SignalR's JavaScript client).